# HTTP.Request not returning expected data

Tags: f#-data

If I enter a value directly on the web form and click `submit`, it returns a record.  When I run the code below, it does not return a record in the response body.

```
Http.Request("https://efiling.dir.ca.gov/PWCR/Search.action", body = 
FormValues ["conCSLB", "22"])
```

What am I missing?